# Compile C# code in R-package on all OS (Windows, Linux and MAC)

Tags: c#, .net, r, operating-system, r-package

I would like to create an R-Package as R interface for a C# program.

At the moment it works quite well by just using the shell or system function on windows.

```
shell("C:/path/to/executable.exe")
```

This is clearly not satisfying as an .exe file is not working on Linux or MAC.

As I have the possibility to include the C# source code into my package and theoretically compile it while installing it on any OS, I was wondering if and how I can achieve that.

The rClr package seems to be an option but I am having trouble to understand how to actually use it for my purpose.

So my first question is:
Is it possible to do what I am trying to do or is it simply not possible and should I discard my wish to make the package usable on all OS?
If so it would save me a lot of time and I can do something else.

My second question would than be: If it is possible, how can I do it and where do I start?